# Android : using the network in a service

Tags: android, networking, service

Making a call to a REST WebService in a Service class of my Android app create the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

I understand why this exception is raised in an Activity : fetching something over the network synchronously is an extremely bad practice but I am surprised to see that same error in a Service Class.
So my question is :

-In this specific case, should I use `StrictMode.setThreadPolicy()` to allow this call. *(And for those that read this because they have encountered this error in an activity, don't use StrictMode to hide this error, use an AsyncTask)*

-or should I use an AsyncTask ? And in that case, what is the issue here ? Isn't the service on a thread separated from the Activity's one ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Even though [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) is intended for background processing they run in the **main thread** .

A short quote from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html):

> Caution: A services runs in the same process as the application in which it is declared and in the main thread of that application, by default. So, if your service performs intensive or blocking operations while the user interacts with an activity from the same application, the service will slow down activity performance. To avoid impacting application performance, you should start a new thread inside the service.

The 'background processing' means that service has no user interface, it can run even if the user isn't directly interacting with the application. But all the background processing still happens in the main thread by default.

So, how to solve it and get rid of the exception? As the documentation suggests you have to use a background thread. In your service you can use `AsyncTask` or create threads directly. But I guess  [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) might be the most suitable in your case. `IntentService` processes requests in the background thread (so that's the kind of service you were  looking for).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so that's what I suspected. I assumed that since they are used for background tasks Services would be on another thread by default, but it is not the case.  
  
Actually i use that service to manage calls to 'MediaPlayer', so having it on the main thread does not sound like it will be an issue since 'prepareAsync()' allows me to manage its behavior elegantly.
I will just have to modify my service in order to use an 'AsyncTask' to get the streaming url.

Comment: Good answer, there are also materials available that will help you to understand how to use the network efficiently, to ensure your app is optimized. http://developer.att.com/developer/forward.jsp?passedItemId=7200042

Answer (score 0):

Service run in main thread, thats why you ned to do something like

```
public class ServiceDownloadSomething extends Service {

private static final String TAG = ServiceDownloadSomething.class.getSimpleName();

private boolean isRunning;
private Thread backgroundThread;

private Runnable myTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while (true) {

            //sleep 30 seconds
            long sleepTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + (15 * 1000);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime - System.currentTimeMillis());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                //perform network action
                downloadSomething();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
};

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    this.isRunning = false;
    this.backgroundThread = new Thread(myTask);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if(!this.isRunning) {
        this.isRunning = true;
        this.backgroundThread.start();
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    this.isRunning = false;
}

private void downloadSomething() throws IOException {

    URL url = new URL("http://192.168.197.101:8080/api/medias/");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    // Starts the query
    conn.connect();

    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int r;
    do {
        r = is.read();

        if (r != -1){
            sb.append((char) r);
        }

    } while (r != -1);

    String json = sb.toString();
    Log.d(TAG, json);

}
```

}